# Why holding key does a single key press in python?

Tags: python, input, macros, keyboard

I'm currently developing a small macro software in Python to allow the user to automate common tasks in a simple way (a kind of 'Super macro' brought up to date for those who are familiar with it).

I'm currently working on creating a function that allows the user to manipulate the keyboard, but I'm stuck on keypresses! Typing text is not a problem, pynput makes it very easy to do, but for a continuous keypress (for example, holding down 'a' for 1 second), I can't seem to figure it out :(
The result is always a simple keypress and not a key held down for a specific duration.

I'm using Windows 10, with Python 3.10.5 and Azerty keyboard.

I've tried simulating a keypress with many Python libraries, and none of them seem to work! I'll share the code I'm using to test the libraries, but at this point, I'm starting to think the issue might not be with Python but with my PC's configuration. I've tried running VSCode as an administrator, creating an .exe and running it as an admin, but no luck! I've tested the code to write in Notepad, Word, Google Chrome, and VSCode, but nothing happens :/

Here's my test code:

```
import time
import ctypes
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
import win32api
import autoit
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as PynputController

def press_key_pynput():
pynput_keyboard = PynputController()
pynput_keyboard.press('a')
time.sleep(1)
pynput_keyboard.release('a')

def press_key_pyautogui():
pyautogui.keyDown('a')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.keyUp('a')

def press_key_keyboard():
keyboard.press('a')
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.release('a')

def press_key_pydirectinput():
pydirectinput.keyDown('a')
time.sleep(1)
pydirectinput.keyUp('a')

def press_key_ctypes():
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
VK_A = 0x41
user32.keybd_event(VK_A, 0, 0, 0)
time.sleep(1)
user32.keybd_event(VK_A, 0, 2, 0)

def press_key_win32api():
VK_A = 0x41
win32api.keybd_event(VK_A, 0, 0, 0)
time.sleep(1)
win32api.keybd_event(VK_A, 0, 2, 0)

def press_key_autoit():
autoit.send("{a down}")
time.sleep(1)
autoit.send("{a up}")

def press_key_pywinauto():
send_keys('a')
time.sleep(1)

def simulate_key_press():
time.sleep(2)
press_key_pynput()
time.sleep(1)
press_key_pyautogui()
time.sleep(1)
press_key_keyboard()
time.sleep(1)
press_key_pydirectinput()
time.sleep(1)
press_key_ctypes()
time.sleep(1)
press_key_win32api()
time.sleep(1)
press_key_autoit()
time.sleep(1)
press_key_pywinauto()

simulate_key_press()
```

The result is : aaaqaaaa (I noticed the 'q' but it does not mater since nothing is working as expected)

I've done quite a bit of research, and I did find people who had the same issue, and the response was always either running it as an admin or compatibility issues with the software they were trying to simulate keypresses in (which is why I tried Notepad, Word, etc.).

I've created a temporary solution by implementing a loop that presses the key every x milliseconds, but I'm not too happy with it, and I like to understand how things work (or why they don't work) ^^

If anyone has any ideas, I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: No one has a clue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this has to do with how you are testing whether the key is being held down. I've had this problem several times, and usually it has something to do with that. I'm assuming that you're expecting an output like this: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", like when the user actually presses and holds the key down, the key is repeatedly typed.

For example, with `pyautogui`:

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.keyDown('a') #holds the key 'a' down
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.keyUp('a') #releases the key 'a'
```

When you run this code, you'll probably get an output something like this: "a".

This is *not* an error, the key is being pressed down (at least in my case). Usually, when a user presses a key down and holds it, the key is repeatedly typed. In the case of a virtual key press using `pyautogui`, for some reason (I don't know why this occurs), the letter is only typed once (but the key is still being held down). If you truly wanted the output: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", you could simply use `pyautogui's typewrite()` function, like this: `pyautogui.typewrite("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")` and that would work. The way I knew (at least for me) that the key was being pressed was by a specific test I ran. I opened up an online web browser game, that involved pressing and holding down the key 'w', and ran `pyautogui` code that held the key down. Both the program and the game worked, which is how I knew that the key was really being held down.

For my experience, this was only for `pyautogui`, so I don't know if this is the case for other modules as well. You should try running the same test as I did, with `pyautogui`, to see if the key is being held down.

Comment: Ho man! Thanks for your answer! You are right, I just tested the same function using the up arrow to scroll on a web page and it worked! I putted this function aside since I was working on others and I was waiting for an answer about the keyboard issue, but it seems there never was a problem!
So I guess I will make two functions, one to repeat the key an obtain 'aaaaaaa" and another one to have both possibilities.
Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! It seems it was only the applications (and the keys I tried) who were blocking the key repetition. Solution is to create a loop if you want to have your key printed multiple times, and most of the holding functions works fine (you just won't see multi-prints but the key will be hold). If you have troubles with it, try different apps and different key combinations to know which solution is better for you.